# Parse a string with two different delimiters into an associative array

Tags: php, split, text-parsing

I have a string variable like the one below.   I'm trying to split it into an array or even into separate variables for each element (change, day high etc.).

```
$a='last: 901.5001 @ 11:35am EST 11/10/2011 <br>change: -5.9999 <br>day high: 
921.50 <br>day low: 882.00 <br>open: 917.50 <br>volume: 808998';
echo $a;
```

Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on `<br>` first, then split on the first colon:

```
$temp = explode("<br>",$a);
$data = array();
foreach ($temp as $item) {
   list($name, $value) = explode(":", $item, 2);
   $data[$name] = $value;
}
```

should output:

```
Array
(
   [last] => 901.5001 @ 11:35am EST 11/10/2011
   [change] => -5.9999
   [day high] => 921.50
   [open] => 882.00
   ... etc ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
$tmps = explode('<br>', $string);
$arr = array();
foreach($tmps as $tmp){
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $tmp,2);
    $arr[trim($key)] = trim($val);
}
var_dump($arr)
```

you can change the line `$arr[trim($key)]` to `$arr[]` if you do not care of what was before the `:`

Comment: Probably David intends to split it again with ':' to get i.e. `$arr['day high'] = 921.50`

Answer (score 0):

```
$step_one = explode('<br>', $string);
foreach($step_one as $step_two)
{
    $step_three = explode(': ', $step_two);
    $final[$step_three[0]] = $step_three[1];
}
var_dump($final);
```

Or to get what's in your comment:

```
$step_one = explode('<br>', $string);
foreach($step_one as $step_two)
{
    $step_three = explode(': ', $step_two);
    $final[] = $step_three[1];
}
var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string matching (especially regular expressions) on HTML can be dangerous as any slight variation may mess things up. But if your code is known to be good:

```
preg_match_all('/([^:]+):(.+)<br>/U', $a.'<br>', $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$a = array();
foreach ($m as $v) $a[$v[1]] = trim($v[2]);

var_dump($a);
```

If you don't want the keys then it just becomes:

```
preg_match_all('/:(.+)<br>/U', $a.'<br>', $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$a = array();
foreach ($m as $v) $a[] = trim($v[1]);
```

Or even:

```
preg_match_all('/:\s(.+)\s<br>/U', $a.'<br>', $m);
$a = $m[1];
```